# Nonlinear model fit not working

Tags: nonlinear

Probably a very simple fix, but I'm trying to fit a simple exponential. Even when I put in good guesses, the model won't fit the data. Any suggestions?

```
<< StandardAtmosphere`
data = Table[{alt, MeanFreePath[alt Quantity[1, "Kilometers"]][[1]]}, {alt, 0, 110, 0.5}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, A*Exp[(x - B)*C], {A, B, C}, x];
Show[ListLogPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 LogPlot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 110}, PlotStyle -> Black], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Altitude (km)", 14], Style["MFP (m)", 14]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide your Mathematica code, not an image!

Comment: Your data does not seem to have a unique value for an given altitude.

Comment: Added code. The data is the exponential line and the nlm result is the flat line.

Comment: @icebox207 You should probably use `LogPlot` instead of `Plot`,  to match the `ListLogPlot` you used for your data. We can't investigate further because `MeanFreePath` is not defined in your code, so we can't run it.

Comment: MeanFreePath is loaded with the ```StandardAtmosphere``` package, added.

Comment: I don't know the subject matter but an exponential fit doesn't work with `alt > 100` so one shouldn't extrapolate with an exponential model. (Also, `MeanFreePath` clearly (?) uses linear interpolation at alt = 80, 85, 86, 90, 95, 100 and many other values of alt.  Again, I don't know the subject matter but that isn't mentioned in the documentation.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Needs["StandardAtmosphere`"]

data = Table[{alt, MeanFreePath[alt Quantity[1, "Kilometers"]][[1]]}, 
     {alt, 0, 110, 0.5}];
```

Fit the log of the data

```
Exp[(nlm2 = 
    NonlinearModelFit[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ data, a*x + b, {a, b}, x]) //
   Normal]

(* E^(-16.8632 + 0.147609 x) *)

Show[
 ListLogPlot[data,
  PlotStyle -> Blue],
 LogPlot[Exp[nlm2[x]], {x, 0, 110},
  PlotStyle -> Black],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Altitude (km)", 14], Style["MFP (m)", 14]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Alternatively, since

```
A*Exp[(x - B)*C] == Exp[Log[A]]*Exp[C*x - B*C] == 
  Exp[C*x - (B*C - Log[A])] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The model has only two parameters. Use `Exp[a*x + b]`

To determine initial estimates for the [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), use two widely separated data points

```
paramEst = 
 SolveValues[Exp[a*#[[1]] + b] == #[[2]] & /@ data[[{1, -1}]], {a, b}][[1]] //
   Quiet

(* {0.148094, -16.5286} *)

(nlm3 = NonlinearModelFit[data, Exp[a*x + b], Transpose[{{a, b}, paramEst}], 
    x]) // Normal

(* E^(-17.0152 + 0.153491 x) *)

Show[ListLogPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 LogPlot[nlm3[x], {x, 0, 110}, PlotStyle -> Black], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Altitude (km)", 14], Style["MFP (m)", 14]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To long for a comment:

Mathematica v12.2 evaluates much better result as shown in your question. Try

```
<< StandardAtmosphere`
data = Table[{alt, MeanFreePath[alt Quantity[1, "Kilometers"]][[1]]}, {alt,0, 110, 0.5}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, A*Exp[(x - B)*C], {A, B, C}, x];
Show[ListLogPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
LogPlot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 110}, PlotStyle -> Black], Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["Altitude (km)", 14], Style["MFP (m)", 14]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrich! Unfortunately I just tried this verbatim in Mathematica 13.3 and I get the same result as in my post.